# Ideas for making a function for counting number of zero's in a bit string in C?

Tags: c

Can I make a function int bitParity(int x)  that returns 1 if x contains an odd number of 0's using only these operators?  ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Comment: Yes you can - why not have a go?

Comment: A friend of mine asked me the question and only said to use those operators.

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Then you should either do it or say you can't.  He wasn't asking if WE could figure it out.  (Still, sounds like homework or an interview question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, it was exactly three clicks.
google -> 1.st result - wiki/Parity_bit -> external link -> 
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive